# Stripe upgrade subscription handling

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I just want to confirm that using the stripeAPI to update a subscription plan updates it synchronously, and I can trust the response given by the API and I do not have to rely on Webhooks to update the plan.

Thanks for the clarity.

Answer (score 2):

The subscription update operation is synchronous, but the customer might not be billed immediately.

If the original plan and the new plan have the same billing interval (e.g. monthly), Stripe will compute the proration but not bill the customer immediately. The original billing schedule will be maintained and the result of the proration will be added as invoice items to the next invoice.

You can read more about this here: https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/upgrading-downgrading.